# TeXStudio 3.0.1: No Dictionary Available

Tags: texstudio

I recently did a fresh install of TeXStudio 3.0.1 on Windows 10, and it no longer checks spelling.  I have the .dic, .aff, etc. files that come with the default installation, but the program does not recognize them.  It only gives me the option to import .oxt files.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check that spell check is enabled in the status bar.
[image]